# Will running a separate thread that uses a method from the main thread still run it on the main thread? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, md5sum

I'm working on a project that requires me to some multitasking on md5 check-sums. I created a very simple way to handle the md5 check-sums by creating a new thread and using a method that allows me to reuse the different algorithms.

**Here's The code for my new thread:**

```
private readonly Thread md5Check_ = new Thread(new ThreadStart(md5Check));
```

**Here's the handler for that thread:**

```
private static void md5Check()
    {
        string config_integrity = GetChecksum(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "/file.txt", Algorithms.MD5,).ToLower();

    }
```

**(This is written in the same MainWindow.xaml.cs file) Here's the GetChecksum method:**

```
public static string GetChecksum(string fileName, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), 100000))
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(algorithm.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

**And the algorithms:**

```
 public static class Algorithms
    {
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm MD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm SHA1 = new SHA1Managed();
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm SHA256 = new SHA256Managed();
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm SHA384 = new SHA384Managed();
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm SHA512 = new SHA512Managed();
        public static readonly HashAlgorithm RIPEMD160 = new RIPEMD160Managed();
    }
```

I was wondering since the new thread (md5Check_) calls the getChecksum method on the main thread, if the actual calculations would be calculated on the new thread (md5check) or the main thread as if the file is 1GB or 2GB my application could appear to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any **method called from the thread will be executed on the calling thread** unless you manually dispatch it via **Dispatcher (in WPF)** on other thread.

Also in your case you can verify yourself by using [**Thread.CurrentThread**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in GetChecksum() method to see on what thread it is currently executing.

Answer (score 1):

This will run on the new separate thread

Answer (score 1):

With the current code (assuming you call `md5Check_.Start()` somewhere), your code will run on the thread you created (md5Check_).

Comment: You too. Thankzzz adv12.